# Android switch spinner doesn't appear immediately

Tags: android, spinner

I've figured out how to show some text after selecting an item from the spinner, with switch case..
But now the text doesn't appear immediately if I select an item.

When I choose an item for the first time, "spotinfo" remains empty.
When I choose a second item, then it adds text to "spotinfo".

Can somebody tell why the text doesn't appear immediately?

```
public class InputItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos , long id) {
          spotInfo.loadData("", "text/html", "utf-8");
          String data = "<div style=\"color: #949494;\">";

          switch(parent.getSelectedItemPosition()){
            case 0:
                data += getString(R.string.Panoramaterras);
                break;
            case 1:
                data += getString(R.string.about);
                break;
          } 

          data += "</div>";
          spotInfo.loadData(data, "text/html", "utf-8");
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
      // Do nothing.
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Which item are you selecting first?  If you're selecting an already selected item, then onNothingSelected is called instead.

Although you may not have selected anything manually, the Spinner calls onItemSelected after initialization.  If you don't want this behavior to happen, you should wrap your code in a boolean check that is set after the spinner first initializes.

```
boolean hasSpinnerLoaded = false;

public class InputItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    public void onItemSelected(...) {
        if (hasSpinnerLoaded) {
            //do your switch statement here
        }
        else
            hasSpinnerLoaded = true;
    }
}
```